# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS freezes during installation in the same spot - dual/triple boot process

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I was doing triple boot initially on MAC with Win 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Windows 10 is getting installed without a glitch. It is Ubuntu is getting stuck in the same spot - two-thirds done during kernel source configuration. It is happening when Ubuntu comes to the screen with the message starting "Check out askubuntu.com".

Now I switched to dual boot on MAC with Ubuntu 14.04 and got the same freeze in the same spot.
Ubuntu partition is properly formatted with the swap (32Gb) in-front every time.

Any ideas, please???

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have burned a bad image. Your download may have gone wrong, or it may have been while transferring to your DVD/USB.

I'd recommend that you download the ISO file from Ubuntu again, and give it another try.

Also, 32Gbits (4GB) is a good amount of SWAP space, but I'm assuming you meant 32Gbytes, and that would be much bigger than required.